# Как составить запрос чтобы узнать кто из самолетов меньше всего летал?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psql

Я из таблицы хотел узнать сколько полетов сделал каждый самолет, а из этого узнать кто меньше всего летал. НО, так как я в синтаксисе не очень еще разобрался, как и в подзапросах, то мне нужна помощь...
**Таблица:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось узнать **список самолетов** и сколько они пролетали раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я пробовал и не получилось:

```
SELECT MIN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights GROUP BY aircraft_code) AS min, aircraft_code FROM flights;  


SELECT MIN(SELECT countt FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as countt FROM flights GROUP BY aircraft_code) ), aircraft_code FROM flights;  

SELECT MIN(countt),  flights.aircraft_code FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as countt FROM flights GROUP BY aircraft_code) tbl WHERE flights.aircraft_code = tbl.aircraft_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать созданную Вами таблицу  Список самолетов, пусть она будет называться fl2, например. Тогда

```
    WITH fl2 AS (
```

* здесь прописываете всё для создания таблицы fl2*\

```
    )
    SELECT aircraft_code,count FROM fl2
    WHERE count IN
          (
          SELECT MIN(count) FROM fl2
          );
```

Т.о, за поиском MIN Вы обращаетесь к созданной таблице fl2 со списком самолетов.